# Reading iframe contents in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

I have an iframe in my cshtml

```
<iframe id='my_iframe' name='my_iframe' src=""></iframe>
```

The content of which I read using my jquery

```
var uploadDocResult = $('#my_iframe').contents().find('p').html();
```

Which is successful in chrome but not in IE.
How do I read the iframe contents using jquery in IE?

Comment: Is it a reasonably versioned IE (10+?) or something you found in some ancient Greek ruins?

Comment: The IE I have is 11. So, any ideas?

Comment: Several, I would first be inclined to check what the contents() method returns in chrome and IE to check if they return the same thing. Rumor has it that when doing this with pure JS chrome would return the document while IE would return the window. Second thought is making sure that the iframe is fully loaded before attempting to get the content.  These things tend to be case specific, your code should work under normal circumstances so the problem might be in the specifics.

Comment: I got Access is denied on IE. And iframe does not seem to load the content at all.

Comment: Any chance you have the basic auth crendentials in the `src` link (e.g. `src="http://user:pass@example.com/"` ? ) IE doesn't like those.

Comment: No, I haven't added credentials like that.